# Run In Host Machine Batch File to load/call a batch file in guest machine virtualbox

Tags: batch-file, virtual-machine, virtualbox, host, psexec

I need to run in host machine with Windows 7 a batch file that execute some software inside the batch file and after run/call another batch file in guest machine virtualbox with Windows 7.

I tryed some solutions witout success.

```
Host machine have windows 7
Path batch file host machine C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\test1.bat
User Host Machine "Windows" Password "123456"

Guest machine have windows 7
Path batch file guest machine C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\test2.bat
User Guest Machine "Windows" NO Password Setted
```

How can I excute a batch file in host machine and after call a batch file in guest machine ?

On Virtualbox there are installed Guest additions latest version.

I need to use a batch file in host machine and a batch file in guest machine because inside I add a list of software to open.

I tryed this solution too without success, I installed psexec.exe and after add in batch file this code

```
psexec.exe \\<SERVER_NAME> -u "<GUEST_USER>" -p "<GUEST_PASSWORD>" -i -d "C:\script\script.bat"
```

Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Is this possible? I need same